# nav bar to stay on top after reaching top of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to emulate this http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/F4BmP/ 
in the "result" section you see how the nav bar remains at top of the page as soon as it reaches top of the page when scrolled. I used the same code but my nav bar doesn't stay on top; it continues scrolling. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my code:

html

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href=".\favicon.ico">
        <title>rentPRO</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var num = 210;

            $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
                        $('#top_menu').addClass('fixed');
                } else {
                        $('#top_menu').removeClass('fixed');
                }   
            });
        </script>   
    </head>
```

css

```
#header {
    background-image: url("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4epq8pWSUKQ/VNX4lGi_GrI/AAAAAAAAAIo/9gDg5CubDO8/w1044-h201-no/header%2Bfinal1.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 1075px;
        height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    }

#top_menu {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 210px;
    left: 136px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14.85px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 1075px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-color: #A4A4A4;
    }
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28394620/4255615), it gives you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Changing '`top_menu`' to a class instead of an ID worked for me.
Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npdqe28m/).

HTML:  `div class="top_menu`"
CSS:  `.top_menu`

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
              $('.top_menu').addClass('fixed');
         } else {
              $('.top_menu').removeClass('fixed');
         }   
    });
});
```

Comment: can i please send you my html file for you to check? i'm copying and pasting what you've provided but it is not working

Comment: sure, you could also edit the original post to include the full html so other users can help too.

Comment: the fiddle is working just fine; i'm getting the desired result but i don't know what's wrong with my code. my code is not doing what the fiddle is doing

Comment: The fiddle you sent me wasn't working because the jQuery library wasn't on. Here's the fiddle with jQuery activated http://jsfiddle.net/rq18on66/

Comment: Also, to make sure the jQuery isn't running before the page is ready, make sure your code starts with `$(document).ready(function(){` jsfiddle takes care of that for you but in a real-world application you need to include that yourself.

Comment: still not working :S
my code is exactly the same as in the fiddle and the fiddle gives the required result but not my code. and i've wrapped the jQuery with $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: Well if the code is working in the fiddle then it must be an issue with how you're setting up/deploying that code. Maybe it's not finding jQuery, maybe jQuery is being called at the wrong time, maybe you've turned off JS somehow. Use your browsers Dev Tools to diagnose the problem, then come back here if you still need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your Javascript with the document ready function. It should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var num = 210;

  $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
      $('.top_menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $('.top_menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }   
  });
});
```

Comment: Try changing the '#' id selector to a '.' class selector

Comment: Also - ensure that you're loading jQuery