# Sticky Header on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, nav, sticky

I am currently designing a new website and have a 100% responsive layout, width and height.

I have a header that sits 0px from the bottom of your screen. Once scrolled past I would like the header to gain a class of "sticky" which then sits the header at the top of the page in a fixed format.

Currently I can only find the jquery code for when you hit a certain pixel on the page the nav sits at the top. However I have a percentage based site so the pixel at which the header sits will be different on every computer screen.

Does anybody have the correct code for me to use to sit my header at the top of the screen once scrolled down.

I have added an image to explain.
Thanks.

My current jquery code is:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height() ) {
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('header').addClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

However this doesn't seam to work.
[image: sticky nav example]

Comment: Where is your CSS code?

Answer (score 1):

For your css try this:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

This will keep the header stuck to the top of the screen. Alternatively you could just give the header `position: sticky;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) but your browser support will be pretty limited (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Answer (score 1):

Is this of any help? [JQuery Position:Fixed 'NAVBAR' by scrolling the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187317/jquery-positionfixed-navbar-by-scrolling-the-page) in that page there is a demo too, look for the marked answer.

You can also try this plugin I wrote long time ago [Simple-Sticky-Top-Navbar](https://github.com/dcdeiv/Simple-Sticky-Top-Navbar). It's a while I'm not updating it, but hey, you can always fork it and tweak it the way you like :)